# CORS enabled Web API fails to add header

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am using the `DynamicPolicyProviderFactory` as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn532203.aspx).  Below is my version of the DynamicPolicyProviderFactory:

```
public class DynamicPolicyProviderFactory : ICorsPolicyProviderFactory
{
    private readonly HashSet<Regex> _allowed;

    public DynamicPolicyProviderFactory(IEnumerable allowedOrigins)
    {
        _allowed = new HashSet<Regex>();

        foreach (string pattern in allowedOrigins.Cast<string>()
            .Select(Regex.Escape)
            .Select(pattern => pattern.Replace("*", "w*")))
        {
            _allowed.Add(new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase));
        }

        if (_allowed.Count >= 1)
            return;

        //if nothing is specified, we assume everything is.
        _allowed.Add(new Regex(@"https://\w*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase));
        _allowed.Add(new Regex(@"http://\w*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase));
    }

    public ICorsPolicyProvider GetCorsPolicyProvider(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        var route = request.GetRouteData();
        var controller = (string)route.Values["controller"];
        var corsRequestContext = request.GetCorsRequestContext();
        var originRequested = corsRequestContext.Origin;
        var policy = GetPolicyForControllerAndOrigin(controller, originRequested);
        return new CustomPolicyProvider(policy);
    }

    private CorsPolicy GetPolicyForControllerAndOrigin(string controller, string originRequested)
    {
        // Do lookup to determine if the controller is allowed for
        // the origin and create CorsPolicy if it is (otherwise return null)

        if (_allowed.All(a => !a.Match(originRequested).Success))
            return null;

        var policy = new CorsPolicy();
        policy.Origins.Add(originRequested);
        policy.Methods.Add("GET");
        policy.Methods.Add("POST");
        policy.Methods.Add("PUT");
        policy.Methods.Add("DELETE");
        return policy;
    }
}

public class CustomPolicyProvider : ICorsPolicyProvider
{
    private readonly CorsPolicy _policy;

    public CustomPolicyProvider(CorsPolicy policy)
    {
        this._policy = policy;
    }

    public Task<CorsPolicy> GetCorsPolicyAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(this._policy);
    }
}
```

My call to register the cors win the WebApiConfig.cs

```
 config.EnableCors();
 config.SetCorsPolicyProviderFactory(new DynamicPolicyProviderFactory(Settings.Default.AllowedDomains));
```

And my application settings being passed:

```
<MyApp.Properties.Settings>
  <setting name="AllowedDomains" serializeAs="Xml">
    <value>
      <ArrayOfString xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <string>http://localhost</string>
        <string>http*://*.domain1.com</string>
        <string>http*://*.domain2.com</string>
      </ArrayOfString>
    </value>
  </setting>
</MyApp.Properties.Settings>
```

Despite these settings, the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is not present on my responses if I make a request from `http://mg.domain1.com` to `http://localhost`.  I am using Web Api 2.2 and Microsoft.AspNet.Cors 5.2.2.

**edit:** I have found that if I use the `EnableCors` attribute on the controller, or enable it globally (`config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*"));`) it works, so it must be something with my dynamic factory.  The frustrating thing is, the DynamicPolicyProvider is copy/pasted from another project I am using that works fine.

**edit 2:**   Success!...I enabled [tracing](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/tracing-in-aspnet-web-api) and found the error

```
 The collection of headers 'accept,content-type' is not allowed
```

So I just edited the `GetPolicyForControllerAndOrigin` method to allow them.  Now everything works, except I am confused because I did not have to jump through this hoop in my other project (the one I copied the DynamicPolicyProviderFactory from).

Comment: It's amazing how complicated they made the CORS setup with multiple different ways of how you can set it up where each one "almost works" and the documentation is terrible, all over the place and doesn't explain half the stuff you're supposed to implement to make it work.

Comment: @pootzko I definitely agree! Also Mike_G, can I just put the DynamicPolicyProviderFactory.cs in the root folder or does it have to go in a certain folder? What is this: `</MyApp.Properties.Settings>`, I can't find it anywhere in Web.config. Is that the `appSettings`?

Comment: @Si8 The `DynamicPolicyProviderFactory` is just like any other class and can organized under any code folder.  for the `MyApp.Poperties.Settings`, it is in the web.config, but if you want a UI for editing that specific section, the right click on your project in VS > Properties > Settings

Comment: That helped, thank you. So I don't have to add [EnableCors()] above each API file?

Comment: Also when I added it through properties, it removed the `ArrayOfString` and each `string` attribute and just listed the domain in Web.config file.

Comment: So `<string>http*://mysite/*</string>` allow `http://mysite/mysubsite` to call the API?

Comment: No, you do not need to add `[EnableCors()]` to an action or control.  If you edit the app settings in the web.config by hand, it will mess it up in the UI editor.  I just generally use the UI editor to create the sections in web.config (so I don't have to write all the xml for setup), then just hand edit it.

Comment: No, just use `<string>http*://mysite.com</string>` (will hit http and https)or something like `<string>http*://*.mysite.com</string>` to include sub domains.

Comment: I am sorry, it is a SharePoint sub site... so something like `http://mysite` and `mysubsite` is the subsite of `http://mysite`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enable [tracing](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/tracing-in-aspnet-web-api) in the app.  You should see an error

```
The collection of headers 'accept,content-type' is not allowed
```

Just add these to the allowed headers for the policy and everything should work.