# In ASP.Net Web API 2, is it possible to require cors only requests

Tags: cors, asp.net-web-api2

I have my Web API setup with CORS access from my domains, but people can still go to the service directly. Is there a way to require that the origin is one of my domains?

Comment: It sounds like you want to white list your domains and block everyone else, is that correct?  if so, check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22511627/subdomain-cors-in-webapi-2/27069923#27069923

Answer (score 0):

You probably have something like this:

```
var corsAttr = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
config.EnableCors(corsAttr);
```

Just replace the first * with a list of domains e.g.

```
var corsAttr = new EnableCorsAttribute("example.com,another.com", "*", "*");
```

See documenation on this constructor [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.cors.enablecorsattribute.enablecorsattribute(v=vs.118).aspx).